# strcpy_s for char** and char[][]

Tags: c++, arrays, char, strcpy

I used `strcpy_s` as below:

```
char names[2][20];
strcpy_s(names[0],"Michael");
strcpy_s(names[1],"Danny");
```

and it worked all right.

But when I changed to `char **`,

```
int size1=2;
int size2=20;

char **names=new char*[size1];
for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
  names[i]=new char[size2];
strcpy_s(names[0],"Michael");
strcpy_s(names[1],"Danny");
```

It gives me this error message:

> error C2660: 'strcpy_s' : function does not take 2 arguments

Why is this happening? I need to dynamically create char arrays, so what should I do?

Comment: `strcpy` != `strcpy_s`. Which one did you mean to use?

Comment: As this is C++, consider using a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @hmjd Don't consider using it. Use it.

Comment: @user1203803 high and clear!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two forms of `strcpy_s` (at least on Windows): one for pointers and one for arrays.

```
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char *strDestination,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource 
);
template <size_t size>
errno_t strcpy_s(
   char (&strDestination)[size],
   const char *strSource 
); // C++ only
```

When using pointers you have to specify the number of elements of the destination buffer:

```
strcpy_s(names[0], size2, "Michael");
strcpy_s(names[1], size2, "Danny");
```

Comment: +1 was unaware of the template version (even though it was on page I linked in my deleted answer!)

Comment: @Michael No problem. Don't forget to click the green check mark to accept the answer as correct.